# Rotate a vector around an axis

Tags: linear-algebra

What happens when you rotate a vector $\vec{a} (0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ around the x-axis? Shouldn't it just become $\vec{a}(0,-1)$, or have I got a completely wrong idea about rotations around axes?

Comment: How many degrees do you rotate by ? why is the $a$ missing in the second expression $(0,-1)$ ?

Comment: Isn't rotating around the x-axis sufficient? Like, a complete rotation? Or not?

Comment: From what you have written, $(0,-1)$ is a *reflection* about the $x-$axis of the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: That clears up my confusion! I'm sorry, I mixed up reflection and rotation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, the vector $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is transformed into the vector $(0,-1)$ by a *reflection* in the $x$ axis. However, one can also consider $\mathbb R^2$ canonically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$; in that case, $(0,-1)$ could also be regarded as the result of *rotating* $(0,1)$, embedded as $(0,1,0)$, through $\pi$ about either the $x$ axis or the $z$ axis.